# How to retrieve an img src value from an un-loaded wordpress post?

Tags: javascript, mysql, css, wordpress

What I'm trying to do here is basically make the background of a loop post's div background-image.

Pseudo code looks something like this:

```
 if this.post has an img tag {
  store the img tag's src into a var,
  then use that img src var as the background-image of the div which holds the permalink to the post
 }
```

Does this make sense? I'm thinking I'll have to retrieve the src from within the WPDB, but I really have no idea how to not only get that data from the WPDB, but also get it into a var that can then be used inside the div as the background-image...

I know, a pretty tall order and probably a big learning curve for me. But That's how we learn right! :)

Thanks in advance, anyone.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'Featured image' of a Post. First, activate the Post Thumbnails by adding this to your `functions.php` file:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
```

You can then retrieve the featured image using the following code:

```
$image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID));
```

Then apply that to your div:

```
<div style="background-image: url(<?php echo $image_src; ?>);">
```

Comment: I had a feeling it would be something like that! Thanks so much for the code snippets too. I put your first code into the functions.php, the second into the header and the style into the appropriate div, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, you can do something like this in javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('img').each(function(){
    var $containingDiv = $(this).parent();
    $containingDiv.css('background-image', 'url(' + $(this).attr('src'));
  });
});
```

You have to change `$(this).parent()` to point to the actual element that shall get the background. `$(this).parent()` is the parent element of the img element.

Note: This will handle all images in the html document. You might want to limit the scope in the image selector. If for instance the html element that is parent of the image has class name 'post', you can do:

```
$('.post > img').each(function(){
```

To find what you actually need, you might want to check out the jQuery documentation for selectors: 
http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/.